# Maximum Possible Deceleration when braking

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

I have this problem set question and I am not sure if I am overthinking it or not.

> Suppose you are driving at velocity $v$ on a horizontal road that has a coefficient of static friction $µ_s$ with the tires. You need to stop suddenly and step on the brakes. If the road is straight, what is the maximum possible deceleration?

So far I have started by saying that the car exerts a force forward (mass of car X acceleration of car) and friction acts in the opposite direction of the car.

When the car is braking, it essentially stopping and sliding across the surface. How do I relate this to the velocity?

Edit: Is it overthinking the question to say that the car is initially constantly accelerating to maintain a constant velocity and then to use that information to my advantage i.e as part of a system?

Comment: Hint: what's the maximum force the ground can apply to the car, due to the friction force between the ground and tires?

Comment: At constant velocity, there is no acceleration. And the question is not about velocity.

Answer (score 0):

The acceleration of the car before applying brakes is irrelevant.

Brakes stop the wheels from rotating. And maximum deceleration is achieved when the wheels completely stop. So, the force that decelerates the vehicle is the frictional force. It has nothing to do with the initial acceleration of the car or the value of $v$.

$ f= \mu_s N $

Considering the road to be perpendicular to the direction of the gravitational force,

$N = mg $

Thus, maximum deceleration is,

$ a= -\mu_s g $